# Measuring cumulative number of events in a day

Tags: poisson-process

A certain type of event happens in continuous time throughout the day.  During some periods of the day (say between 9 am and 5 pm) the event happens more frequently than outside of these times.  Given we have observed the times at which each event occurs (and consequently their inter-arrival times), I'd like to know how to model the expected cumulative number of events as a function of time of day, as well as obtain uncertainty estimates for the cumulative number of events.

To start, let's imagine we have pairs $(t_i, X_i)$, where $t_i$ is the time of day, and $X_i$ is the inter-arrival time between event $i$ and $i-1$.  If the $X_i$ were IID, we could model this as a Poisson process.  But, since $X_i$ is related to $t_i$, that assumption seems to be violated.  I was thinking I could do a sort of exponential regression so that $X_i \sim \operatorname{Expon}(\lambda(t_i))$.  From there, I could do a parametric bootstrap to get estimates of the cumulative number of events in a day.

Open to any other methods, or to hear I am wrong.

Comment: Do you mean to say you view this is a problem in [estimating rates of an inhomogeneous Poisson process?](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39&as_vis=1&q=inhomogeneous+poisson+process+estimation&btnG=)

Comment: @whuber  There is always a name for it.  Thanks for that, will read some of these